# Validating input box while form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've made a form where input boxes will appear dynamically where some have required="required" and some doesn't. I'm submitting this form with ajax and I want to alert something through Jquery / Ajax  whenever the required fields are empty. The names of input boxes are dynamic like name[], roll[]. How can I achieve this ?

//Sample

```
<form action="page.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label style="font-size:15px">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" value="" required>
    <input type="text" name="class[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your class" value="">
   </div>   
</form>
```

Same input boxes comes up dynamically by clicking on add more and I have to submit it and want to alert an message through Jquery when required field is empty.

Comment: Can you provide the code or even better a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Where is your code, what have your tried?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the onblur function. When the user clicks on the input box the onfocus function is triggered and when afterwards the user click somewhere out of the input box the onblur function is triggered. So, you can check if the input's value is empty or not when the onblur function triggeres like in the code below:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter your name" value=""
    onblur="if (this.value=='') alert('MY MESSAGE');"
    required>
```

Is this what you wanted? Did it work? please let me know.

**EDIT**

In order to get the alert when the user clicks submit you should give an id to the input box (e.g. `inputId`) like this:

```
<input id="inputId" type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter your name" value=""
    onblur="if (this.value=='') alert('MY MESSAGE');"
    required>
```

and then add this to your form tag:

```
<form id="main_form" action=""
    onsubmit="if (inputId.value=='') { alert('MY MESSAGE'); return false; }">
```

AJAX Code:

```
function register_post() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "check.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData($("#main_form")[0]),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#get_det").html(data);
            document.getElementById("register_post").submit();
        },
        error: function(data) {
          alert("There was an error. Please check details and try again.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No, It gives an error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Also, it will only alert if the user focus on that input box. What if the user clicks submit without focusing in the input box ?

Comment: Forgot to close the apostrophe `('MY MESSAGE')`. Try again the edited code.

Comment: But, what if the user didn' focus in the input field ?

Comment: I fixed a little mistake now. Try again. Does it work?

Comment: I already told that my input fields are dynamic and I need to do it with jquery. I don't have to use id rather I can use name and it can be 1 or 2 or 100 because it's dynamic.

Comment: You can add the id in the jquery at the time you create the input boxes. Since you don't provide the jquery code I can't just assume it. Perhaps the jquery code needs modifications. How do you create the input boxes?  Please provide the jquery code if you want more help.